# PHP - new Object in array

Tags: php, arrays, class

```
class Player 
{
    public $name;
    public $stack;
    public $action;

    public function __construct($stack, $action)
    {
        $this->action = $action;
        $this->stack = $stack;
    }

}

class Hand
{
    public $BB;
    public $SB;
    public $ante;
    public $isSB = TRUE;
    public $hero = 1;

    public $players = array(
        new Player(1800,200);
        new Player(2000,0);
        new Player(2400,100);
        new Player(2600,200);
    );

}


$h = new Hand();
echo $h->players[$h->hero]->stack;
```

I got parse error. 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_NEW, expecting ')' in...
How can I add object to this array? Is there a better solution?

Comment: You cannot do that. First items in arrays are separated by a comma. Second: you need to do that in a method.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to move it to the constructor

```
class Hand
{
    public $BB;
    public $SB;
    public $ante;
    public $isSB = TRUE;
    public $hero = 1;

    public $players ;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->players = array(
           new Player(1800,200),
           new Player(2000,0),
           new Player(2400,100),
           new Player(2600,200),
        );
    }

}
```